# HTML5 generate canvas background image

Tags: html, canvas

I have this image that I made in photoshop, and I would like a way to recreate it using HTML5 Canvas, so that javascript is creating the same image (or similar).. It would make the page loading faster, since no image has to be downloaded also.

It is a pretty simple image. Three different colors blurred or placed as gradients ( I don't know how to do it) and then a white gradient from the bottom fading out to transparent after maybe 60px. I have seen so many incredible things made possible using canvas element, and this is the same image every time, and with no animations. Also I would like it to scale automatically when the window is resizing.

Does anybody know how to create something like this?

[image]

Comment: Just read HTML5 canvas functions drawImage() and createLinearGradient() and also createRadialGradient() and make some stuff .. then if you find any problem then just ask Question here at SO..

Comment: Just a note, with proper caching, you can eliminate the download time for the image after the first time. Also, depending on the size, you can make it light.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha :) Thank you.. I am aware of that.. I would just like to make the client (browser) make as much work as possible, since it would make the browsing experience a lot more fluent and nicer..

Comment: @PuzzledBoy good question. It's very versatile. We actually have to request the OP to give his tried version first. But often people are just giving answers anyway. It's not exactly encouraged to promote cookbook-style answers for somehow who didn't show effort, but it's not like it's against policy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start here http://jsfiddle.net/5pR46/1/:

**CSS**

```
#wrapper canvas {
    position: relative;
}

#wrapper canvas {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
    <canvas id="myCanvas2" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function drawRadial(elemId, startColor, endColor, x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById(elemId);
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

    context.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // create radial gradient
    var grd = context.createRadialGradient(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1);
    grd.addColorStop(0, startColor);
    grd.addColorStop(1, endColor);

    context.fillStyle = grd;
    context.fill();

    delete canvas;
    delete context;
    delete grd;
}

drawRadial('myCanvas', 'rgba(248,173,133,1.0)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.0)', 50, 25, 110, 300, 50, 400);
drawRadial('myCanvas2', 'rgba(213,215,155,1.0)', 'rgba(0,0,0,0.0)', 500, 150, 110, 500, 50, 600);
```

You can add as many layers as you want. Just add another;

```
<canvas id="myCanvas#" width="578" height="200"></canvas>
```

.. where `#` is the new number of your layer (keep them in the correct order to get the correct results tho. You could even go as far with JavaScript as just start with an empty `#wrapper` and just fill it dynamically with `canvas`-incremented ID's and then binding the full drawing procedure to it. Giving you super clean code while maintaining control over the content.

Play around with the coordinates and the size of the radials and it'll fit soon enough like you want it. I'll leave the rest of the creativity to you ;)

Comment: This really make sense o me thanks. :) I have one thing though.. I think it is a bit dark compared to my image.. something I can do to make it lighter? Think it is caused by the transparency, but i don't know.. http://jsfiddle.net/5pR46/3/

Comment: I found out thanks. :) To avoid the darkness, set the ending color to be the same as the start color, and only change the opacity. In that way, it won't become dark.. see this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5pR46/4/

Comment: why not merge canvas together ?

Comment: @r043v I chose this to show for simplicity, as it's easier to understand the layers by placing numbered canvas elements on top of each other than doing complex canvas actions. Performance-wise it wouldn't really matter much if I benchmark 10 merges vs 10 separate canvas elements. Thanks for the feedback tho :)

Answer (score 2):

you can also try do it with old school method :- )

using an algorithm to generate the colors array

exemple for a pink gradent :

```
var colors = [];

for(var x=0;x<width;x++)
    for(var y=0;y<height;y++)
    {   var red = 0x6b+(x>>2)+(y>>2); if(red>0xff) red = 0xff;
        colors[y*width+x] = (red<<16)|(0x2b<<8)|0xc6;
    }
```

and use some code to extract each color r,g,b to fill the canvas with it

```
while(i < size){
    color = colors[i]; // get color

    // extract r,g,b ...
    var r = (color>>16)&255;
    var g = (color>>8)&255;
    var b = color&255;

    // fill buffer with each color part
    buffer[n++] = r;
    buffer[n++] = g;
    buffer[n++] = b;
    buffer[n++] = 255; // alpha to max
    i++;
}
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/r043v/FTuPC/9/